# Shell code to check if a device or file with spaces in the path is mounted

Tags: linux, mount

The search results that I've turned up have either been about determining whether a filesystem is mounted at a particular path or whether a particular path is being used as a mount point. I am looking for a way to determine whther or not a given device or file (i.e., a filesystem image) is mounted *at all*. This solution should be able to handle spaces in the path to device/file.

These, which I have seen in my search results, are NOT solutions:

- `mountpoint -q "${PATH}"` only tests if `${PATH}` is a mount point.
- Applying `grep -q "${PATH}"` to some output may not work because `${PATH}` may have spaces in it and the output of commands like `mount` has spaces in it.

Additionally, it should return WHERE a file/device is mounted to.

Comment: The difficult part it is handling a mount point with space. So I would put such important point also on the title of thew question.

Comment: Did you try to grep through **/proc/mounts** ? It should have all informations you need.

Comment: @Kalavan If the source is something `/home/user/fs`, but another file/device is mounted at `/home/user/fs_mnt`, then `grep` is pretty useless.

Comment: @Melab That's why you grep for the device name, not the mount name.  /etc/mtab (for RH and similar systems) stores the mount information for all currently mounted filesystems.  So you grep for the device name in /etc/mtab.  See the answer provided by a0f3dd13.

Comment: @Xalorous Except if `/home/user/fs` *is* a device name…

Comment: @Melab Nothing under /home is a device.  This is where users' profiles are stored.  A device could be MOUNTED in a folder in that location, but the devices belong in /dev.

Comment: @Xalorous It's an example. And who is to say that is so? I can create a device node anywhere I want with `mknod` (except on paths to filesystems mounted with `nodev`)!

Answer (score 3):

You can consult the file `/proc/self/mounts` (or `/proc/mounts`), in this file spaces are encoded using \040 (octal value):

Example, `/dev/sda1` is mount in `/mnt/mount sda1`

```
grep '/dev/sda1' /proc/mounts | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Return: `/mnt/mount\040sda1`

```
grep "$(echo '/mnt/mount sda1' | sed 's/ /\\\\040/g')" /proc/mounts | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Return: `/dev/sda1`

Answer (score 0):

/etc/mtab, /proc/mounts and so on do not display the source file path.

**mount** commands does and formats its output.

So you could try to:

```
mount | egrep "${file_path=} on /"

export file_path="/home/kalavan/Downloads/debian 6.0.10-amd64-netinst.iso"

mount | egrep "${file_path=} on /"
/home/kalavan/Downloads/debian 6.0.10-amd64-netinst.iso on /mnt/pc75 type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
```

In opposite to

```
mount | grep debian               
/home/kalavan/Downloads/debian 6.0.10-amd64-netinst.iso on /mnt/pc75 type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
/home/kalavan/Downloads/debian 6.0.10-amd64-netinst.iso_somethingelse on /mnt/projekte type iso9660 (ro,relatime)
```

The risk of mistake is much smaller then. One could also try to match rest of line pattern wit a regexp.